# How to install Wilkner's sanskrit package skt?

Tags: languages, indic

I have been searching various forums to know how to install the skt package (Wickner). I tried using tlmg. No success. Am running Ubuntu 18.04.I personally find it better than typing in the devanagari script. Wickner's package is the most perfect, imho, from the way the text appears.

Comment: In order to use `tlmgr` you should install "vanilla" TeXLive: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1092/how-to-install-vanilla-texlive-on-debian-or-ubuntu

Comment: Alternatively install the ubuntu package `latex-sanskrit`, it should contain the latex package `skt`

Comment: thank you Is this "latex-sanskrit" package the same as "sanskrit" package?. I am not an expert. I read the description about installing vanilla. It is quite daunting. I hope I will not break my system. (latex installation)

Comment: Could someone please help?  I don't want to create double posts. I tried installing latex-sanskrit. it failed.I installed devanagari package. processing failed (devanagari.sty not found). My requirement is to create sanskrit documents (suktas) with the svaraas (udata, anudata and svarita). Someone said, I should install skt.c from CTAN. but did not say how.  my question is : how to install skt package or sanskrit package and from where and how. My requirement is to generate sanskrit text with svaras.

Comment: You don't actually give enough information to help you. How did you try to install the packages?  How did it fail? What were the error messages?

Comment: Not sure if everything will fit in here

Comment: sudo apt-get install -y latex-sanskrit

sudo apt-get install -y latex-sanskrit
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package latex-sanskrit is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'latex-sanskrit' has no installation candidate

Comment: Looks like you have to install vanilla TeXLive after all

Comment: For some reason the `skt` binary is no longer distributed with TeX Live, but you can get `skt.c` from CTAN and compile it yourself.

Comment: There's a question about this on this site somewhere (search for "skt.c") but if you can't find it I'll post an answer here

Comment: Thank you. I found something. Not sure if this is what it is. 

https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/327312/how-to-make-the-skt-c-preprocessor-work/327327#327327

However, I don't understand the comment about downloading the skt file from winer's site. I would appreciate a set of instructions for downloading and compiling that I could understand. Apologies if this sounds not very clever.

Comment: @Srinath Very sorry about the delay; I had promised to post an answer here but I forgot (or rather didn't realize that 3 days have passed already). I have posted an answer now; hope it is still helpful.

Comment: Feel free to ask more questions if something doesn't work (e.g. not even clear whether you're on Windows or Linux or macOS, so you may not have a compiler on your system...)

Comment: A million thanks. I am using Ubuntu 18.04. I have successfully compiled the skt.c and got the executable. My earlier tests in processing gave me the error "sanskrit.sty not found" and later with the Devanagari I got "devanagari.sty not found".

Comment: I tried exactly the same code above: my filename wik.skt
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{skt}
\begin{document}
Let us say {\skt te_ja_svi naa_vadhii!tamastu|} now.
\end{document}

processed it with ./skt wik.skt  

Result:

SKT.C Version 2.2.1 2016-08-31
No input text
A tex file was created. But it was empty. Absolutely no text in it
no logfile was created
and the contents of the original file (wik.skt) was also deleted

what could be wrong?

Comment: @Srinath Seeing this only now (please note that I won't get notified of your comments here unless you start them with `@ShreevatsaR` — or you can just comment on my answer instead of commenting on your question). Anyway, it looks like “No input text” is printed if the input file is empty (as far as the program can tell). You could try just `./skt` and enter the file name later. Also please check whether the input file is in the same directory.

Comment: @Shreevatsa No problem. Thank you for your reply. Both the pre-processor and the source file are in the same directory. I had copied and pasted the source from here and pasted it into the file. My question is where could the error possibly be? Something is wrong somewhere.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR tried what you suggested. Entered the file name later. got a tex file. However when I ran pdflatex on the tex file I got the old error message 

! LaTeX Error: File 'skt.sty not found'

Comment: @Srinath Ah looks like the package is missing. If you're using the Ubuntu TeX Live, then it's in package `texlive-lang-other` — so `sudo apt-get install texlive-lang-other` should do it.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR A millilion Thanks. That did the trick. Excellent help. Problem solved. Thank you

Comment: @Srinath Great to hear and glad to help; just for completeness I've updated my answer below to mention this too. If you wish, you can click on the green tick next to the answer, to mark it as having solved your problem.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR Thank you. I have clicked it. Now I can use the skt package and create documents with the vedic accents.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`skt` package](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/sanskrit) originally by Charles Wikner has two parts:

- The style file `skt.sty` and `mf` sources etc.
- A preprocessor named `skt` which is a separate binary.

The former is available in TeX Live; if you're using TeX Live from the Debian/Ubuntu system then it is in the OS package called `texlive-lang-other` (so can be installed with `sudo apt install texlive-lang-other`).

The latter, the `skt` binary, used to be distributed with TeX distributions (I think), but is no longer distributed with TeX Live. (Not sure why.) So you have to compile it yourself:

1. Get `skt.c` from CTAN: it is available at http://mirrors.ctan.org/language/sanskrit/skt.c and you can just save the file. If it has been saved as `skt.c.txt` (say), then you need to rename it back to `skt.c`.
2. In a terminal (command line), run `gcc skt.c -o skt` (or you can use any other C compiler you might have available).

That's it; now you can use the package as documented.

---

For example, write the following into a `test.skt` file:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{skt}
\begin{document}
Let us say {\skt te_ja_svi naa_vadhii!tamastu|} now.
\end{document}
```

Now run the binary you had compiled above:

```
./skt test.skt
```

This will create a `test.tex` file that looks like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{skt}
\begin{document}
Let us say {\skt .te\ZK{`8}a:j\ZK{`8}a;\ZH{0}{i0////Y7}a;s1va
na;\ZK{`8}a;va;Di6a;\ZK{`7}a;ta;ma;s1tua\ZS{12}@A} now.
\end{document}
```

This you can compile the usual way:

[image: result]

If you have never used a terminal or C compiler before you may have to look up how to do that. Good luck!

Comment: I'm able to create the documents, but the resolution in the pdf is quite low, whereas the Latin alphabets are looking fine. How to increase the resolution of the Devanagari letters?

Comment: @IsomorphicBunny Could you post a new question, with details about the TeX distribution and operating system you're using, and the full output of the commands you used to compile the LaTeX file? On my system with `pdflatex test.tex` I see Type1 fonts being used in the output (which are vector fonts that scale smoothly to any resolution), but it seems like your system is using bitmap fonts. (You could use `\pdfpkresolution=2400` to get higher-resolution bitmap fonts but really you should be getting vector fonts.) Also post the output of `kpsewhich pdftex.map` and `kpsewhich skt10.pfb`.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I installed `sanskrit` package from MikTeX, but at the time didn't install `sanskrit-t1` which is the type1 version of the `skt` fonts. I'm now able to make high-resolution documents.